What exactly is the Rarita-Schwinger field?
i keep reading that the Rarita-Schwinger field represents a spin-3/2 particle and that it is a "vector-spinor" or "vector-valued spinor" that's great but what does it mean actually?
when speaking of vectors for example, we can talk about the vector (the whole thing) or its components, which are scalars. same goes for spinors. i don't understand how we treat the RS-field under this view, however. what does the index of the RS-field exactly mean?

Mean? what do you mean for it to mean? Your links are impeccable. What are they missing?

I would recommend trying to grasp integer-spin/bosonic fields before half-integer-spin/fermionic fields. Scalars and vectors and tensors are, arguably, easier to understand than spinors.

A vector-spinor has one vector index and one spinor index. The latter is often implicit, as in Thomas Fritsch’s answer. Under Lorentz transformations, a vector-spinor transforms in a direct product of a vector representation and a spinor representation.

its components, which are scalars You have an incorrect understanding of what “scalar” means to physicists. A scalar is not just anything that is a single number. It is a single number that doesn’t transform under whatever transformation one is considering. The components of a vector do transform and therefore are not scalars.

In the Rarita-Schwinger equation
$$(\epsilon^{\mu\kappa\rho\nu}\gamma_5\gamma_\kappa\partial_\rho-im\sigma^{\mu\nu})\psi_\nu=0$$

$\mu,\kappa,\rho,\nu$ are space-time coordinate indices.
That means they are $=0,1,2,3\ $ (or $=t,x,y,z$ if you prefer like this).
Each $\gamma_5$, $\gamma_\kappa$ and $\sigma^{\mu\nu}$ is
a complex $4\times 4$ matrix.
See also Gamma matrices for the definition of the $\gamma_\kappa$.
Each $\psi_\nu$ is a Dirac spinor (i.e. with $4$ complex components).
That means $\psi$ is a $4$-vector, where each of its $4$ vector components
is a Dirac spinor.

